# Как искать русский текст в django?

Tags: django, sqlite

Есть необходимость организовать поиск русских слов. Из документации к django понятно, что при использовании базы SQLite поиск ведется с учетом регистра. Как можно это обойти? Вот такой пример использования поиска:

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product  

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        get_params = self.request.GET.dict()

        # search
        if get_params.get('q'):
            qs = qs.filter(product_title__icontains=get_params.get('q'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `__iregex` - Регистронезависимая проверка регулярным выражением.

```
Entry.objects.get(product_title__iregex=r'^[а-яА-Я]/$').all()
```

Ссылка на документацию: https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/models/querysets.html

Comment: @Holovko, Спасибо. Но ругается на скобку (или её отсутствие): qs = qs.filter(product_title__iregex=r'^[а-яА-Я]/$'=get_params.get('q'))

Comment: В чем проблема ее добавить?)

Comment: Куда? Если так: `qs = qs.filter(product_title__iregex=r'^[а-яА-Я]/$')=get_params.get('q')` - то тоже ругается.`SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call`

Comment: Эта строка похожа на билиберду, а пайтон билиберду не любит и ругается.

Comment: Что вы хотите сделать? Какая задача? Чем вас мой пример не устраивает?

Comment: Я хочу организовать поиск, используя гет праметры.

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8`

Comment: Вот есть неплохой пример https://overcoder.net/q/18026/когда-использовать-get-getqueryset-getcontextdata-в-django

Comment: Все очень сложно. Нужно писать новое представление. Я хотел бы использовать старое, как в моем случае. Это не решение.

Comment: В чем заключается вопрос? В регистре поиска?

Comment: Да. Я же описал. Это связано с конкретной базой. Проблема известна.

Comment: Я через 2 часа сяду за ноут, буду тестировать конкретно ваш пример.

Comment: Спасибо. Мне люди написали, что это требует большого кода. Так что нереально.

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/445634